# Created DirectShape is not extracted through forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I generated (in debug mode an addin) DirectShape as a Volume of a Room as in:
https://github.com/jeremytammik/RoomVolumeDirectShape

Rooms are generated and REVIT file is saved correctly, then I send it to FORGE for processing and I extract Model View Metadata Properties (mvmp) and the OBJ.

The issue is that MVMP does not contain any information of recently generated room volumes, the object is:

DirectShape ds = DirectShape.CreateElement(doc, _id_category_for_direct_shape);

```
                ds.ApplicationId = id_addin;
                ds.ApplicationDataId = r.UniqueId;
                ds.SetShape(geo.ToList<GeometryObject>());
                ds.get_Parameter(_bip_properties).Set(json);
                ds.Name = "Room_Max_is_an_okayish_dev_" + r.Name;
```

The question here is: how should I modify it so it will be included in the extraction mvmp.json?
I suspect I need to tag it somehow or add it to some sort of collection.

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Revit, you can define which [views are to be included in the Forge translation process](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/revit-20181-nuget-packages-rooms-and-views-in-forge.html#2).

Ensure that you see your direct shapes in at least one of your Revit views, and that this view is earmarked for translation to Forge.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, I applied the config as explained: ![Revit Publish settings](https://ibb.co/BnyrtPq). Uploaded it to Autodesk Viewer, where on the thumbnail I can see the volume: ![Thumbnail](https://ibb.co/6YJjsCt). When exploring file the volume is displayed as a thin layer on top of the room ![Valid XHTML](https://ibb.co/Rg4HNQh). Finaly uploading it to FORGE I get the metadata containing more views ![Valid XHTML](https://ibb.co/gvGpFcm) but when I download the .OBJ the desired volumes are not there, and I need them. Recap: there are no 3D rooms in viewer and there are no volumes in .obj

Comment: OK, understood. Checking with the devteam for you.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, a quick update that I did not explain earlier, what I do have extracted through forge is the same thin layer from the top of the volume as in: [Sample](https://ibb.co/Rg4HNQh). it is a 2D object on top side of the room.

Comment: Initial feedback: Revit Extractor (Derivative service channel `viewing-rvt-lmv` and `viewing-rvt-lmv-large`) does not generate `obj` from `rvt`. It generates `svf` instead. According to your description, '... but when I download the .OBJ the desired volumes are not there'; it seems you translate `svf` into `obj`, where problems on rooms appear. According to Translation Extractors List, channel `ds-data` and `ds-data2` translate `svf` into `obj`. They are checking for further info now...